# How to search for a specific string in an string array in C# 3.0

Tags: c#, arrays, search, c#-3.0, for-loop

I'm trying to search for a string in a string array in C# but I'm not sure how. 
So, if the array has 50 elements, most of them null, how would I go about searching for a string in the array?
For example:

```
string[] this_array;
this_array = new string[50];
this_array[1] = "One, Two, Three";
this_array[2] = "Foo, Bar, Five";
this_array[3] = null;
```

How would I go about searching for "Five" in this_array? I understand I have to use a for loop, I'm just not sure of the actual code. I have to find the exact index so I cannot obtain a boolean.

Any help would be much appreciated!
Jamie

Update:
Here's my, very incomplete code, so far:

```
for (array_number = 1; array_number < this_array.Length; array_number++)
{
  //no idea what to put here :S
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this home work? Have you tried using a  `for` loop? If yes, where exactly are you stuck? :)

Comment: Why do you have multiple values in a single element of the array.  That is a horrible design decision.

Comment: I feel you haven't actually bothered searching on a search engine for this sort of problem before posting. I've just typed in a question in google about finding text in a string and I'm swimming in correct results. You should also look up how a for loop works.

Comment: I admit it's horrible but I'm very new to C#. And yes, it's homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this...

```
int index = -1;
string find = "Five";

for(int i = 0; i < this_array.Length; i++)
{
   if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(this_array[i]))
      continue;
   if(this_array[i].ToLowerInvariant().Contains(find.ToLowerInvariant()))
   {
      index = i;
      break;
   }
}
```

NOTE: My search is case-insensitive. If you care about the casing of characters the remove both instances of .ToLowerInvariant()

Comment: you would probably want to perform the `ToLowerInvariant` on the find string as well.

Comment: Why on earth would you not just add (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this_array[i])) to the Contains conditional.  Of course there are better ways like Fabio suggested.  I have to vote this down because of the poor techique.

Comment: @pstrjds, thanks I meant to put that but must have forgot by the time I typed all the rest (need Intellisense here!)

Comment: Thanks @musefan but that didn't seem to work - it processes fine (i.e. there aren't any errors outputted) but it doesn't find the string.

Comment: @Ramhound, Firstly Fabio's does not do what was asked. And I did not want to pollute the IF statement for this example, it is already big enough for someone to understand that does not know how to use loops for this kind of thing yet. Plus, I doubt my way would compile any differently than your suggestion

Comment: @Jamie, see my edit. I had missed a bit that pstrjds had pointed out

Comment: If you do care about this remaining case-insensitive, it would be a good idea to perform the `ToLowerInvariant` on the `find` string outside the bounds of the for loop, since it's value is constant throughout the loop. There is no need to repeatedly perform that operation in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use Linq. It's the easiest and less error prone way.

Add a using statement to the top:

```
using System.Linq;
```

And search like this.

```
var result = this_array.Where(x => x != null && x.Contains("string to compare"));

if (result != null) System.Writeln(result.First());
```

Comment: OP is looking for a "contains" search not an exact search

Comment: Works only where the whole string matches the search string - would not find "Five", as described in the question.

Comment: @pstrjds: `C# 3.0 != .NET 3.0`. C# 3 release coincided with .NET 3.5, which does include LINQ.

Comment: downvoted because is does not answer the question and uses Linq, which (unless I am mistaken) is not available in .Net 3.0, which this question is clearly tagged as and is even stated in the question title.

Comment: @Marc My bad, I just googled and saw you are correct about that. I thought the C# 3.0 equated to .Net 3.0. Glad there is consistency in the numbering :) The answer still doesn't handle the contains portion of the question though.

Comment: @pstrjds, it now contains the Contains method.

Comment: @Fabio - Downvote now reverted, although it still doesn't completely answer the qeustion. I believe `First()` will return a string. The question asks about finding the index - "I have to find the exact index so I cannot obtain a boolean."

Answer (score 1):

Here is some sample code for you. This will find the first index for a matching entry.

```
int foundIndex = -1;
for(int i=0; i < this_array.Length; ++i)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this_array[i]) && this_array[i].Contains(searchString))
    {
        foundIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this was homework, I'd recommend you familiarize yourself with the methods available in the String class:

[String Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string_methods%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

MSDN is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

```
for(int i=1;i<this_array.length;i++)
    if(this_array[i]!=null)
        if(this_array[i].indexOf("Five")>-1
            return i;
```

That is roughtly c# code - I may have made some minor errors. But surely you could achieve this yourself. Also, I think there are probably better ways of doing this.

Comment: doesnt compile, and if it did you could hit an index out of bounds error with the wrong search string

Comment: it is only rough. And it will sort of work. It was the quickest way of typing it. It should point towards the right solution.